# Call particular method in Julia

Tags: julia

Assume I have the following:

```
abstract Spam
abstract Egg <: Spam
foo(::Spam) = 42
```

I now want to add a method `foo(::Egg)`  which internally calls `foo(::Spam)`.

```
function foo(e::Egg)
    # ...
    foo(convert(Spam,e)) # Won't work. How to do this?
    # ...
end
```

What's the syntax to do this?

Comment: `invoke` is what you were looking for.

Comment: It indeed is! Please turn into answer so I can accept it.